# I cannot get my Python 3.2.2 interpreter to run scripts (.py files) on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

I'm relatively new to Python (and programming in general for that matter) and have been using Dick Baldwin's tutorial "Learn to Program using Python" to teach myself. It's been going pretty well but I've hit a pretty big snag. Whenever I try to run a script (`junk.py, which I've placed in C:\Python32) in the Windows Command Prompt this keeps happening:

```
C:\Users\jeremy>cd C:\Python32

C:\Python32>python junk.py
  File "junk.py", Line 1
     Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep 4 2011, 09:51:08) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
 win 32

Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax
```

I know I have successfully added `C:/Python32` to my list of variables and have no problem running python through my command prompt and [I am pretty sure at least] I have followed all of [Dick Baldwin's instructions](http://www.dickbaldwin.com/python/Pyth0016.htm) correctly. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I can't run junk.py?

Comment: please indicate the content of your junk.py file. If it is  large, create a `print "Hello Word"` script. It seems it is working but there is something wrong in your file

Comment: sorry, I meant `print("Hello Word")` as you are in py3k

Comment: It's just that, though with one space after the "print" command: print ("Hello World")

Comment: What editor/IDE do you use to type the scripts?

Comment: "Python Shell", since it came with Python 3.2.2

Comment: this should work. I have exactly the same setuop than yours on 64bits, and Im running junk.py with no problem. I do not understand why your python junk.py command is giving the heading produced when calling the python shell. And not complete. Did you post the full traceback from your console ?

Comment: Python shell ? Do you mean IDLE ?

Comment: Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:51:08) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> print ("Hello World")
Hello World
>>>

Comment: Well, there's your problem, bad syntax.  Your file should only have this in it:  'print ("Hello World")'

Comment: Can you recommend a better interpreter to use? IDLE won't let me delete the "Type 'copyright' . . . for more information." but I don't know how else to produce a .py file. Thanks for all your answers by the way everybody!

Comment: @JeremyJacob IDLE is a console and an editor. To access the editor, in the menu click on File -> New Window. Working with IDLE is much better if you download IDLEX

Comment: Ok cool I finally got it to work, thanks again everyone!

Comment: @JeremyJacob If you dont like IDLE, the easiest method to get a working IDE without installing any additional python library is PyScripter. My advice is: try IDLE, work for some days with it, code, and after you get more familiar with Python, then look for **YOUR** IDE

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if it has been helpful (click on the green checkmark by the answer you like best).

Answer (score 5):

I got your traceback:

```
C:\Python32>python junk.py
  File "junk.py", line 1
    Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:07:29) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For this my file junk.py has to be (oh! this is really amazing) like this:

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:07:29) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
print ("Hello")
```

that obviously is not a correct python file.

Your junk file has to contain just:

```
print("Hello Word")
```

The Python shell is not the place to edit your files. Use IDLE for that or any text editor from notepad to a full IDE passing through Geany, PyScripter or whatever you prefer

Comment: @JeremyJacob Select the answer if it has been useful to you (checkmark top left of the answer, below the number of points)